# Why does Nest ElasticCleint.Scroll throw System.IO.IOException?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use the Nest method ElasticClient.Scroll; however, the class property ScrollId always returns null and the DebugInformation reads

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection:
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

IndexMany results return a 200 success code. I can use the ElasticClient.Search method and return a Collection of People. Why do I get the error mentioned above?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Elastic elastic = new Elastic();

        NestP nest = new NestP();
        nest.Index();
        nest.Search<Person>();
        nest.Scan<Person>();
    }

}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class NestP
{
    public ElasticClient client { get; set; }
    public NestP()
    {
        Setup();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"))
            .DefaultIndex("people");
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    }

    public void Index()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                Id = i,
                FirstName = "Martijn",
                LastName = "Laarman" + i.ToString()
            };
            list.Add(person);
        }
        IndexName indexName = "people";
        var result = client.IndexMany(list,indexName);
        //returns 200
    }
    public void Search<T>()
    {
        ISearchResponse<Person> searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                        .From(0)
                        .Size(10000)
                        .Query(q => q
                                .Match(m => m
                                .Field(f => f.FirstName)
                                .Query("Martijn")
                                )
                        )
                    );
        var people = searchResponse.Documents;
        // search response returns 200, people.Count == 10000
    }

    public void Scan<T>() where T : class
    {
        var indexName = "name";
        var scrollTimeout = "4s";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        ISearchResponse<T> scanResults = client.Search<T>
                                                (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
                                                    .From(0)
                                                    .Take(1)
                                                    .MatchAll()
                                                    .Scroll(scrollTimeout));

        //scanResults.ScrollId is always null
        //scanResults.DebugInformation == System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
        ISearchResponse<T> results = this.client.Scroll<T>("4s", scanResults.ScrollId);
        while (results.Documents.Any())
        {
            results = this.client.Scroll<T>("4s", results.ScrollId);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Which versions of NEST and elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: Nest Version 7.1.0

Comment: What's in the elasticsearch.log logs? This exception looks like there may be an issue with Elasticsearch you're connecting to, so checking the logs will help to diagnose. An aside: the client sets `Expect100Continue` for the `ServicePoint`, so you shouldn't need to set it